# SOJ socket to PCB

Tags: integrated-circuit, connector, surface-mount, dip, socket

I was wandering, is there some socket for ICs (memory) with SOJ packaging? I mean one that would have contacts that could go through PCB. Like some hybrid between [SOJ socket SMT](http://www.morethanall.com/images/products/175496295148302c5ae8f40.jpg) and [DIP socket](http://www.sc3000-multicart.com/images/SocketExample01.jpg). Or can I use the second mentioned socket directly? I cannot find anything that I am describing.

**edit:**
I am looking for some way to easily changed memory chips SOJ-36 in some socket that would be solder to PCB without SMT technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are the SOJ/PLCC socket adapters, something like [this](http://chufon.sell.curiousexpeditions.org/pz56f008a-plcc-socket-soj-socket-adapter-with-tin-plated-contact-and-84-pin-plcc-socket.html).

To be more [specific](http://www.shopsri.com/pdf/augat/soj.pdf).

Comment: thank you, but is there some type without the need of soldering? What I need is socket that is soldered to PCB so I can easily changed ICs in it. I edited question.

Comment: Ah I get it, the answer is still yes, there is a type without soldering. I edited my comment.